# Binary Search Tree Generics Java

Tags: java, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I am implementing a generic BST in java. The standard BST is in the file BST.java. I also have a subclass which adds additional functionality. I can't seem to get the generics working. I get the following error each time I compare whether in insert, get, or delete:

```
compareTo(Key) in java.lang.Comparable<Key> cannot be applied to (java.lang.Comparable)
    int cmp = k.compareTo(n.k);
```

BST.java

```
public class BST <Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value>
{
    //code here

    public Value Get (Key k)
    {
        Get(this.root, k);
    }

    private Value Get (Node n, Key k)
    {
        if (n == null || k == null) return null;
        int cmp = k.compareTo(n.k);
        if (k.compareTo(n.k) == 0) return (Value) n.v;
        if (cmp < 0) Get (n.left, k);
        if (cmp > 0) Get (n.right, k);
    }

    private class Node <Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value>
    { 
        public Key k;
        public Value v;
        public Node left;
        public Node right;

        //code here 
    }
}
```

BSTExtended.java

```
public class BSTExtended<Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value> extends BST<Key, Value>
{ //code here }
```

Comment: Maybe you have the same problem ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27041694/comparetok-in-java-lang-comparablek-cannot-be-applied-to-java-lang-comparab

Comment: @a_mid I did see that post but still failed to get my code working.

Comment: Please add `compareTo` definition and the calling code (with variables declaration and creation). What is k and n.k? Is it BST or Node, or BSTExtended?

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem was that you were missing explicit references to your type parameters at various points in the definition of the BST class. There were also some pretty basic compiler errors in there.

In particular, have a look at this modified type signature for your Get function:

```
private Value Get (Node<Key, Value> n, Key k)
```

Here's the full class I got compiling:

```
public class BST <Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value>
{
    Node<Key, Value> root;
    //code here

    public Value Get (Key k)
    {
        return Get(this.root, k);
    }


    private Value Get (Node<Key, Value> n, Key k)
    {
        if (n == null || k == null) return null;
        int cmp = k.compareTo(n.k);
        if (k.compareTo(n.k) == 0) return (Value) n.v;
        if (cmp < 0) return Get (n.left, k);
        return Get (n.right, k);
    }

    private class Node <Key extends Comparable<Key>, Value>
    { 
        public Key k;
        public Value v;
        public Node<Key, Value> left;
        public Node<Key, Value> right;

        //code here 
    }
}
```